# Why does my .exe file stop responding after installing using pyinstaller -w filename.py but works fine if I just use pyinstaller filename.py?

Tags: python-3.x, pyinstaller

I currently have a program that takes the user's microphone input and does something with it. I use tkinter and have all aspects of my program presented on the gui so that it doesn't run in the python shell upon execution.

When I install the program using pyinstaller, the executable file opens with the command prompt and works completely fine. When I install the program using pyinstaller -w, the executable opens and then fails to respond after calling for the user's input. I'm not sure if the user input is a factor but it is around that point in which the program stops responding.

I've tried including used packages in the hidden imports section of the .spec file but this didn't work.

I ultimately want to create an executable file that opens without the command prompt and runs normally, regardless of how I build it. (i.e. doesn't matter if it uses pyinstaller or not)

I'm sorry if this is a duplicate somewhere, I've searched for hours and haven't found a solution.

Note: *RuntimeWarning: Couldn't find ffmpeg or avconv - defaulting to ffmpeg, but may not work
warn("Couldn't find ffmpeg or avconv - defaulting to ffmpeg, but may not work", RuntimeWarning)* comes up each time I run the file but it doesn't seem to impact my program's execution.

Comment: does it work when using `pythonw filename.py`?

Comment: @d-k-bo just tried and it does work

Comment: do you use pydub? if yes, this could be related to [this issue](https://github.com/kokimame/joytan/issues/2) and your warning means that pydub can't find ffmpeg. see [this issue](https://github.com/jiaaro/pydub/issues/348) for more information